# How to close a terminal popup through some keystroke(s)?

Tags: terminal-buffer, popup

I want to use a terminal in a popup but I am struggling to close it through some keystroke(s).
Classic keybindings like `<c-w>q` or `<c-w>c` don't work in popups and `<c-c>` won't close the popup if there is a terminal running in it.

At the moment I have set `close: 'button'` in the argument dictionary of the `popup_create` function and I close the popup manually.

It follows the code that I am using:

```
vim9script


def ClosePopup(id: number, key: string): bool
    if key ==# 'q'
        popup_close(id)
        return true
    else
        return false
    endif
enddef

term_start(&shell, {'term_name': 'MY_TERMINAL', 'hidden': 1, 'term_finish': 'close'})
popup_create(bufnr('MY_TERMINAL'), {
    title: "My terminal",
    line: &lines,
    col: &columns,
    pos: "botright",
    posinvert: false,
    maxheight: &lines - 1,
    minwidth: 80,
    filter: ClosePopup,
    minheight: 10,
    close: 'button',
    })
term_sendkeys(bufnr('MY_TERMINAL'), "ls \n")
```

I am suspicious that with this solution there is something to be fixed in the filter function (I am not sure though, just guessing), but I am not sure how to fix it.
At the moment, when I press `q` the character `q` is simply added to the terminal console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an ugly solution that works so far.
Better solutions are welcome.

```
tnoremap <c-w>q <c-w>:QuitTermPopup<cr>
tnoremap <c-w>c <c-w>:CloseTermPopup<cr>

# This function can be called only from a terminal window/popup, so there is
# no risk of closing unwanted popups.
def Quit_term_popup(quit: bool)
    if empty(popup_list())
        if quit
           exe "quit"
        else
            exe "close"
        endif
    else
        if quit
            var bufno = bufnr()
            popup_close(win_getid())
            exe "bw! " .. bufno
        else
            popup_close(win_getid())
        endif
    endif
enddef

command! QuitTermPopup Quit_term_popup(true)
command! CloseTermPopup Quit_term_popup(false)
```